# Change image on the button click in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I am new to iOS development. My current task is to change image on click of a button. The screen will consists of 4-5 images and on click of a button one of the 4-5 images should be change.
Please guide me on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bhaskar M.

Comment: Create a view, add imageviews, add button, implement the image change. if you don't get it work, post the code here and we will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly make a method that will fire when you push a button. And then make something like this

```
-(void) buttonPushed{
   //MyImageView will be the one you need to change
   //you can choose it randomly. It's up to you
   [MyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"qwe.jpg"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your .h file declare an array say `imageArray`.

in .m file `viewDidLoad` use following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[imageArray addObject:@"mage1.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage2.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage3.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage4.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage5.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage6.png"];
[imageArray addObject:@"mage7.png"];

}
```

in your Button Action use following

```
-(IBAction) buttonPushed:(id)sender{

int x = arc4random() % 7;
   //MyImageView will be the one you need to change
   //you can choose it randomly. It's up to you
   [MyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",[imageArray objectAtIndex:x]]]];

//[MyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:x]]];

}
```